# CVXPY generates weird result

Tags: cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

Here's a simple optimization problem:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

w = np.array([700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700])
b = 7000
n = len(w)

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.
x = cp.Variable(n, boolean=True)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(w.T@x), [w.T@x >= b])
prob.solve()

# Print result.
print("\nThe optimal value is", prob.value)
print("A solution x is")
print(np.round(x.value))
```

I want to solve this as an ILP and thus get a result of $x \in {0, 1}^n$. It is fairly easy to see that this will just give `x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` as optimal `x` and optimal value as 7000, and it is indeed what I get. However, if I add `[1800, 1800]` such that `w = [700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 1800, 1800]`, then the optimal value should still be approximately 7000 (all the 700's) but the solver gives 7100 and includes the two 1800's.

I know that it's just approximating the optimal result but in this case it should find the true optimum.

Comment: Are you using the inbuilt toy-solver ecos_bb? Use a *real* solver. More analysis is hard without additional info.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue... Thanks for reply @sascha!